# Promise method 'all' in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to convert my Promise call in jquery and I have a Promise.all method called. What's the equivalent in jQuery?

The current code I'm working with is:

```
w = console.log.bind(console);

var p1 = function p1() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      w('start p1');
      setTimeout(function () {
         return resolve(w('end p1'));
      }, 1000);
   });
};

var p2 = function p2() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      w('start p2');
      setTimeout(function () {
         return resolve(w('end p2'));
      }, 200);
   });
};

var p3 = function p3() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      w('start p3');
      setTimeout(function () {
         return resolve(w('end p3'));
      }, 3000);
   });
};

var p4 = function p4() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      w('start p4');
      setTimeout(function () {
         return resolve(w('end p4'));
      }, 40);
   });
};

p1().then(function () {
   return Promise.all([p2(), p3(), p4()]);
}).then(function () {
   return w('all done');
}).catch(function(){
  //errors from p1, p2, p3, p4
});
```

My intention is to call p1 first and once it succeed call p2,p3,p4. How do I achieve this in jQuery?

thanks

Comment: You are catching errors from p1..4. They will never be passed in together to your catch though, you will either get an error from p1, or from the first failure of p2..4. Please add further explanation as to what is your exact problem. Expected versus actual behavior

Comment: yes excatly, maybe I wasn't clear enough. What I'm trying to achieve is to call p1 first, when it resolves (successfully) it continues and calls p2,p3,p4. If p1 fails it won't continue. If p2 ok but p3 fails p4 won't get called.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)?

Comment: @JuanMendes in fact I used it but then I have to duplicate the .then and .fail functions

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this:

```
w = console.log.bind(console);

var p1 = function() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   w('start p1');
   setTimeout(function () {
      return dfd.resolve(w('end p1'));
   }, 1000);
   return dfd.promise();
};

var p2 = function() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   w('start p2');
   setTimeout(function () {
      return dfd.resolve(w('end p2'));
   }, 300);
   return dfd.promise();
};

var p3 = function() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   w('start p3');
   setTimeout(function () {
      return dfd.resolve(w('end p3'));
   }, 3000);
   return dfd.promise();
};

var p4 = function() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   w('start p4');
   setTimeout(function () {
      return dfd.resolve(w('end p4'));
   }, 400);
   return dfd.promise();
};
```

and I'm calling with

```
p1()
.then(p2)
.then(p3)
.then(p4)
.then(function() {
  // all ok
})
.fail(function(msg){
  // SOMETHING FAILED
});
```

But this is all in sequence. What I want is to call p1, then p2,p3,p4 simultaneously and in case one of this fail, call the fail function.

Comment: You should not post an answer to your own question unless it's actually an answer.  If you need to add more to your question, you can use the "edit" link below your question to add more to it.  Answers should be answers, not additional information about the question.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to call p1, then p2,p3,p4 simultaneously and in case
>   one of this fail, call the fail function.

Using jQuery, you can do:

```
p1().then(function() {
    return $.when(p2(), p3(), p4());
}).then(function() {
    // everything succeeded
}, function(err) {
    // one of your operations failed
});
```

This calls `p1()` and, if it succeeds, then it launches p2, p3 and p4 in parallel and then reports if all succeeded or any one failed.

---

If you just want to sequence them all one after the other, then you seem to already know, you can just do:

```
p1().then(p2).then(p3).then(p4).then(function() {
    // all done here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```